# How to render image in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to render an image in [Highchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX8o7.jpg) and take the place of that blue "spiked disc". [the code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/fanghan/9Lzdf7hw/6/),

```
function onLoaded(chart) { 
    chart.renderer.image('http://localhost:8888/Edtech/Final/nina.png', 
    centerX - 80, 
    centerY - 80,
    160,
    213
) .add();
```

Comment: I am not sure what is your problem with adding image to Highcharts. In your code you need to define centerX and centerY, or not use it at all. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lzdf7hw/8/

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzBlachliński, your solution is really helpful, thank you so much. Now the question is how to render that image into a polygon image, although it's original is rectangle. For example, the original image is rectangle, but I want it is rendered to like a star. Thank you!

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński or render to a circle image.